# How to check that window.pageX is increasing or decreasing in js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, vue.js, mousemove

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    if(magic happens){
        console.log("yes pageX is increasing");
    }
    else{
        console.log("no pageX is decreasing");
    }
});
```

> what is that magic bro plzz tell me?? what is wrong with stack overflow

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the previous scroll height with the current scroll height to find if it is increacing or decreacing.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (this.previousPageY < window.scrollY) {
    console.log("yes pageY is increasing, it's at" + window.scrollY);
  } else {
    console.log("no pageY is decreasing, it's at" + window.scrollY);
  }
  this.previousPageY = window.scrollY;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique aut velit odio maxime ex nam quaerat fugit minima expedita aliquam. Illum itaque rem veritatis odit deserunt commodi inventore nam quo!</span> <span>Beatae inventore voluptate nihil consequuntur iure laudantium adipisci. Molestiae, molestias fugiat ducimus perspiciatis similique et? Inventore accusamus sequi deleniti perspiciatis, consequuntur necessitatibus explicabo est ab omnis labore, debitis dicta nemo.</span> <span>Laudantium illum delectus ipsam quaerat eos ullam cum provident accusamus ex beatae, impedit, obcaecati blanditiis fugiat. Illum ipsum, ullam nam temporibus aspernatur eius deleniti nulla ipsa est sit molestias quos!</span> <span>Dolorum earum illum minus alias repellat illo eaque dolore sapiente. Ad quam dolor est optio, eum autem deserunt dicta dolores dolorum eligendi similique neque, minus eaque? Fugiat dolor aut nisi.</span> <span>Fugit quisquam asperiores, aut officia consequatur distinctio velit iusto molestias eum repellendus, modi animi dolore in facere atque dignissimos quasi molestiae nisi? Assumenda, quia sunt debitis accusantium nihil aspernatur provident.</span> <span>Voluptatem, fuga quis laudantium fugiat animi sequi molestiae totam amet dolorum ducimus quia omnis beatae cum facere harum maiores odio tempora atque. Explicabo illum recusandae est fuga, culpa et fugiat?</span> <span>Accusamus, veritatis. Sint amet dolorem quo recusandae ad praesentium reiciendis, adipisci nihil. Dignissimos nihil nemo deserunt architecto. Facere aspernatur rerum asperiores voluptates sunt. Alias error dignissimos eos repellendus voluptatem. Possimus.</span> <span>At rem, possimus nobis blanditiis quidem totam illo qui perspiciatis, ducimus, assumenda saepe expedita incidunt modi repellat voluptates? Perferendis corporis aliquam fugiat nihil eligendi at? Enim obcaecati commodi esse sed!</span><p><span>Nobis sapiente quibusdam facilis porro. Commodi a est distinctio rerum repudiandae consectetur consequatur ea voluptatum, quia quibusdam modi possimus porro tenetur odio! Voluptatum voluptatibus saepe optio magni aperiam! Deserunt, soluta.</span> <span>Soluta saepe ipsa nemo consequuntur alias ducimus quo quisquam sunt culpa similique quos accusantium animi temporibus, dolorum, deleniti eius nobis veritatis, dolorem natus illo nulla repellat! Fugiat itaque nesciunt cupiditate.</span> <span>Quas consequatur, necessitatibus ex, voluptatem nam incidunt expedita, soluta neque accusantium assumenda dolorem corporis aperiam tempora unde iusto tenetur quisquam quod animi mollitia deserunt hic sed. Non aperiam id blanditiis!</span> <span>Saepe soluta nesciunt repudiandae, est quae delectus accusamus non ullam quo laborum quia? Obcaecati doloribus similique quo totam officiis iure, adipisci sunt ducimus suscipit? Ab iure earum explicabo atque ratione.</span> <span>Repudiandae quis eligendi perferendis eius dolore ea corporis adipisci quod vitae molestiae tempore non esse ipsum ratione architecto, distinctio eos necessitatibus aperiam repellendus repellat tempora! Nobis consectetur quas eum quasi?</span> <span>Facere ipsum est esse fuga id iusto nostrum molestiae non asperiores ducimus sapiente sit ratione voluptas, voluptatibus doloremque molestias quas! Expedita autem facilis consequatur, minus nemo non laboriosam nisi distinctio.</span> <span>Saepe enim id voluptate tenetur nostrum magnam, numquam pariatur labore consequuntur, magni commodi quos suscipit placeat, culpa nulla quae quas fuga incidunt sint quaerat modi minus iusto consectetur. Officiis, numquam.</span> <span>Ex eaque illum amet commodi earum, distinctio perferendis, esse laborum odio iste similique quasi dolorem pariatur nobis reiciendis corporis laboriosam libero. Commodi debitis pariatur dolorem distinctio nam quaerat omnis saepe.</span><p><span>Laudantium expedita, numquam sapiente pariatur quibusdam nostrum aspernatur sed adipisci incidunt commodi, consectetur alias assumenda quasi placeat. Laborum, blanditiis. Eligendi, ea impedit. Optio nobis iste corporis esse illo est aliquid!</span> <span>Animi laudantium cupiditate quidem at nesciunt esse nemo recusandae itaque ratione voluptatum voluptates provident libero earum commodi quo assumenda cum voluptatem, maiores pariatur et dicta quod labore maxime. Reprehenderit, culpa!</span> <span>Obcaecati delectus perspiciatis voluptates, earum quam, dicta quod reiciendis consequatur aliquid velit doloremque ad praesentium pariatur recusandae iure minima eum magnam, harum quo ipsam? Saepe voluptas aut quam perspiciatis placeat.</span> <span>Sapiente veritatis incidunt praesentium expedita corporis, consequatur porro ullam quia unde quod quo laudantium ad error minima, facere ab cupiditate labore necessitatibus sunt exercitationem officia! Quas rerum eligendi cumque voluptas?</span> <span>Repellendus libero maxime doloribus deserunt tempore velit recusandae fugit dolore numquam et magni eligendi dignissimos molestiae saepe ullam vero illum rerum reprehenderit accusamus debitis dicta sint a, in sit. Incidunt.</span> <span>Cupiditate quam quo maiores fuga! Numquam dolorem sed placeat enim tenetur eum ratione reprehenderit aliquam expedita vel. Accusantium aliquid ab cum, quisquam dicta, aperiam dignissimos libero sapiente similique repellendus quas.</span> <span>Enim, obcaecati dolore. Dolore, facere voluptatibus enim fuga officiis quos debitis laboriosam deserunt obcaecati dignissimos numquam harum ea blanditiis eligendi est laborum maxime sapiente. Ad odio voluptates odit a eum.</span> <span>Minima excepturi odio labore blanditiis id, magnam odit? Autem exercitationem nobis voluptatibus, ad nam voluptatem repudiandae veritatis expedita earum voluptate nesciunt! Est omnis autem animi! Soluta tenetur sequi hic non.</span>
```